# How can I stream the screen to an Android device at 60fps?

Tags: windows-10, networking, android, obs-studio

I want to be able to play with my phone (Acting as a screen) to the windows PC, it's not over internet, it's on local. ¿Is there any solution to be able to see my computer screen in my phone at 60fps with no latency? Even 40fps could work.

I tried several tools, but none of them give 60fps, I tried unified remote and Wired X Display and while the last one gives 30fps and no latency, it has framedrops. I tried doing a stream with OBS and while that works flawlessly, it has like 2-3 seconds of latency, so I need something else...

Comment: Make sure the Windows PC is connected via Ethernet to the Wifi router. If it uses Wifi this doubles the required Wifi bandwidth (PC -> router -> phone) and thus doubles the chance if frame drops.